# CMAKE - AIX installation

Tags: c++, cmake, aix

I am fighting with this CMAKE for Wazuh Agent installation issue and I will be thankful for your help.

**Server info>**
AIX 7.1 - Technology Level 5 - Service Pack 8

**Issue>**
Server is not connected to the internet. I am following this Wazuh installation documentation> https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/more-installation-alternatives/wazuh-from-sources/wazuh-agent/
So every dependencies I downloaded by myself.

After I execute wazuh `./install.sh` script, I get **this error>**

```
4- Installing the system

DIR="/var/ossec"

Running the Makefile

grep: can't open /etc/os-release
grep: can't open /etc/redhat-release
/opt/freeware/bin/gmake build_sysinfo build_shared_modules build_syscollector
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/wazuh-wazuh-d9bdabd/src'
grep: can't open /etc/os-release
grep: can't open /etc/redhat-release
cd data_provider/ && mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake -DINSTALL_PREFIX=/var/ossec    .. && /opt/freeware/bin/gmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
**CMake 3.12.4 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.9.1**

– Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:1370: build_sysinfo] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/wazuh-wazuh-d9bdabd/src'
gmake: *** [Makefile:722: agent] Error 2

Error 0x5.
Building error. Unable to finish the installation.
```

---

**So I need to upgrade CMAKE at least to version 3.12.4**

I downloaded 3.12.4 (also higher versions but with same issue), but I got this is error:

```
./bootstrap
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.12.4, Copyright 2000-2018 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found XL toolchain
C compiler on this system is: xlc
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find a C++ compiler that supports both C+11 and the specified C+ flags.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
The C++ flags are "".
They can be changed using the environment variable CXXFLAGS.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /tmp/test/cmake-3.12.4/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

---

**Here is cmake_bootstrap.log>**

```
xlC: 1501-210 (W) command option t contains an incorrect subargument
"/usr/vacpp/include/unordered_map", line 70.5: 1540-0859 (S) #error directive: To use the unordered map library, macro _IBMCPP_TR1_ must be defined
by user to non zero integer value..
"cmake_bootstrap_11272306_test.cxx", line 7.2: 1540-0859 (S) #error directive: "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11.".
Test failed to compile
```

**Information about my compiler>**

```
/usr/vacpp/bin/xlC -qversion

IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V12.1 (5765-J02, 5725-C72)
Version: 12.01.0000.0000

/usr/vac/bin/xlc -qversion

IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V12.1 (5765-J02, 5725-C72)
Version: 12.01.0000.0000

lslpp -l | grep "vac.C"; lslpp -l | grep "vacpp.cmp.core"; lslpp -l | grep "xlC.aix*"
vac.C                     12.1.0.0  COMMITTED  IBM XL C Compiler
vac.C                     12.1.0.0  COMMITTED  IBM XL C Compiler
vacpp.cmp.core            12.1.0.0  COMMITTED  IBM XL C/C++ Compiler
vacpp.cmp.core            12.1.0.0  COMMITTED  IBM XL C/C++ Compiler
xlC.aix61.rte             13.1.3.3  COMMITTED  IBM XL C++ Runtime for AIX 6.1
```

---

Could you please help me, what can I do now, how to install CMAKE to make wazuh installation works?

Comment: `specify one using environment variable CXX.`So try  `CXX=/usr/vac/bin/xlc CXXFLAGS="someflags that you want to use -flag-to-enable-c++11-see -documentation" ./bootstrap`. But the AIX installation from https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/more-installation-alternatives/wazuh-from-sources/wazuh-agent/ does not mention CMake, does it? It uses gmake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did>
'''CXX=/usr/vac/bin/xlc''' and 
'''CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++11'''
Both commands was accepted but error is still same.
Cannot find a C++ compiler that supports both C++11 and the specified C++ flags.

The C++ flags are "".
They can be changed using the environment variable CXXFLAGS.
I am not very familiar with this cmake flags. I never needed to work with this before, so dont know if I did this correctly.
And yes, in that Aix installation wazuh is mentioned Gmake, but in error from installation attemt is mentioned Cmake as dependencies.

Comment: This is __one__ command, not multiple. If multiple, you have to `export` it. So do `export CXX=stuff CXXFLAGS=stuff` and after that `./bootstrap` or do in __one__ line `CXX=stuff CXXFLAGS=stuff ./bootstrap`.

Comment: you can download compiled binary cmake from IBM https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-downloads-alpha

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this is to download the Wazuh package generation tool for AIX (`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wazuh/wazuh-packages/master/aix/generate_wazuh_packages.sh --no-check-certificate`), and run it with `-e` flag: `./generate_wazuh_packages.sh -e`. This script will install all the dependencies you need. Then, you can run again the `./install` if you want to install from sources.
On the other hand, Wazuh has a pre-built AIX package: https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/packages-list.html#aix ready to install using `rpm -i`.